# UTC live clock, not working with negative timezone

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

In my application, I need to create live clock according to different timezones which are stored into database.

I have almost succeeded it.

But now I'm facing negative time in clock, and I'm out of ideas to figure out a solution.

I'm getting UTC time with the help of `new Date()` and calculating time with provided timezone from database.

Case 1: `0:31 (UTC time) + 5:30 (timezone) = '06:01'`

Case 2: `06:31 (UTC time) - 6:30 (timezone) = '00:01'`

Case 3: `5:0 (UTC time) - 7:0 (timezone) = '-02:00'`

Case 1 and 2 is working properly but I'm getting negative value in 3rd case which is wrong.

I have tried to add comments in code to have better understanding of what I'm doing here. I hope it helps.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

```js
function runClock() {

  setInterval(function() {
    //debugger
    var time = new Date();
    // take timezone from HTML element
    // ex: +:5:30
    var getTimezone =  "-:7:0" //$("#timeZone").text();

    // split into array to get oparator (Positive and Negative Timezone)
    var oparator = getTimezone.split(":")[0];
    var timezone = getTimezone.split(":")[1] + ":" + getTimezone.split(":")[2];

    // get UTC hours
    var hours = 5 //time.getUTCHours();
    var minutes = 0 //time.getUTCMinutes();
    var UTCTIME = timeStringToFloat(hours + ":" + minutes);
    var TIMEZONEOFFSETTIME = timeStringToFloat(timezone);
    var finalTime = "";


    // Convert time folloed by Colon into decimals
    // ex: 1:45 = 1.75
    function timeStringToFloat(time) {
      var hoursMinutes = time.split(/[.:]/);
      var hh = parseInt(hoursMinutes[0], 10);
      var mm = hoursMinutes[1] ? parseInt(hoursMinutes[1], 10) : 0;
      return hh + mm / 60;
    }


    // Convert time folloed by float into Colon
    // ex: 1.75 = 1:45
    function floatToTime(FT) {
      var splittedTime = FT.toString().split(".");
      var hh = splittedTime[0];
      var mm = "";

      if (splittedTime[1]) {
        mm = Math.round((splittedTime[1] / 100) * 60);
      } else {
        mm = "0";
      }

      finalTime = hh + ":" + ((mm < 10) ? ("0" + mm) : mm);
    }


    // Calculate time (UTC + or - Timezone)
    // Ex: 00:15 (UTC) + 5:30 = 5:45
    function CalcTime(UTCTIME, TIMEZONEOFFSETTIME) {
      if (oparator == "+") {
        var FT = UTCTIME + TIMEZONEOFFSETTIME;
        FT = FT.toFixed(2);
        floatToTime(FT);
      } else {
        var FT = UTCTIME - TIMEZONEOFFSETTIME;
        FT = FT.toFixed(2);
        floatToTime(FT);
      }
    }


    // Parse Seconds
    function seconds() {
      var j = "";
      if (time.getUTCSeconds() < 10) {
        j = "0" + time.getUTCSeconds();
      } else {
        j = time.getUTCSeconds()
      }
      return j;
    }

    CalcTime(UTCTIME, TIMEZONEOFFSETTIME);

    $("#clockTime").text(finalTime + ":" + seconds());
  }, 1000);

}
runClock();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<b id="clockTime"></b>
```

Comment: Relevant: https://youtu.be/-5wpm-gesOY

Answer (score 1):

You should just be "looping back" to 23:59 when you go negative. You can just add something to check if it goes negative then just re-add the missing time:

```
function CalcTime(UTCTIME, TIMEZONEOFFSETTIME) {
      if (oparator == "+") {
        var FT = UTCTIME + TIMEZONEOFFSETTIME;
        FT = FT.toFixed(2);
        floatToTime(FT);
      } else {
        var FT = UTCTIME - TIMEZONEOFFSETTIME;

        // Offset any negative times;
        if (FT < 0) {
          FT += 24;
        }

        FT = FT.toFixed(2);
        floatToTime(FT);
      }
    }
```

But ideally you really don't want to be handling these kinds of Timezone issues as other libraries are already handling it, i.e. moment.js

```js
function runClock() {

  setInterval(function() {
    //debugger
    var time = new Date();
    // take timezone from HTML element
    // ex: +:5:30
    var getTimezone =  "-:7:0" //$("#timeZone").text();

    // split into array to get oparator (Positive and Negative Timezone)
    var oparator = getTimezone.split(":")[0];
    var timezone = getTimezone.split(":")[1] + ":" + getTimezone.split(":")[2];

    // get UTC hours
    var hours = 5 //time.getUTCHours();
    var minutes = 0 //time.getUTCMinutes();
    var UTCTIME = timeStringToFloat(hours + ":" + minutes);
    var TIMEZONEOFFSETTIME = timeStringToFloat(timezone);
    var finalTime = "";


    // Convert time folloed by Colon into decimals
    // ex: 1:45 = 1.75
    function timeStringToFloat(time) {
      var hoursMinutes = time.split(/[.:]/);
      var hh = parseInt(hoursMinutes[0], 10);
      var mm = hoursMinutes[1] ? parseInt(hoursMinutes[1], 10) : 0;
      return hh + mm / 60;
    }


    // Convert time folloed by float into Colon
    // ex: 1.75 = 1:45
    function floatToTime(FT) {
      var splittedTime = FT.toString().split(".");
      var hh = splittedTime[0];
      var mm = "";

      if (splittedTime[1]) {
        mm = Math.round((splittedTime[1] / 100) * 60);
      } else {
        mm = "0";
      }

      finalTime = hh + ":" + ((mm < 10) ? ("0" + mm) : mm);
    }


    // Calculate time (UTC + or - Timezone)
    // Ex: 00:15 (UTC) + 5:30 = 5:45
    function CalcTime(UTCTIME, TIMEZONEOFFSETTIME) {
      if (oparator == "+") {
        var FT = UTCTIME + TIMEZONEOFFSETTIME;
        FT = FT.toFixed(2);
        floatToTime(FT);
      } else {
        var FT = UTCTIME - TIMEZONEOFFSETTIME;
        
        // Offset any negative times;
        if (FT < 0) {
          FT += 24;
        }
        
        FT = FT.toFixed(2);
        floatToTime(FT);
      }
    }


    // Parse Seconds
    function seconds() {
      var j = "";
      if (time.getUTCSeconds() < 10) {
        j = "0" + time.getUTCSeconds();
      } else {
        j = time.getUTCSeconds()
      }
      return j;
    }

    CalcTime(UTCTIME, TIMEZONEOFFSETTIME);

    $("#clockTime").text(finalTime + ":" + seconds());
  }, 1000);

}
runClock();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<b id="clockTime"></b>
```

Comment: Yeah, I thinking the same, but wasn't sure about this calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You want to recover/display the time for a given timezone offset? Unless you like doing this for a hobby, stay away from string methods and use the date functions, no?

```js
var offsetMS = -5.5 * 3600000
var myDate = new Date()
var dateWithOffset = new Date( myDate.getTime() + offsetMS )
var formatted = dateWithOffset.toLocaleString("en-GB",{timeZone:"UTC",hour:"numeric",minute:"numeric"})
console.log(formatted)
```

Even manipulating timezone offset directly is to be avoided. If you can, use toLocaleString with a real timezone name, then issues like daylight saving will be handled for you. Modern browsers support all iana timezones, so let them do the work.

Comment: The reason of using string is that I'm getting time zone in time format `ex. +5:50` (colon separated), in your case it would be `-5:30`, and if I use your method, I still need to convert time to binary first.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use a library like moment.js that comes with time zone handling and simply need to add/subtract hours from a given date, how about converting them to a common time unit and operating on that?

```
const timezoneString = '-:12:30';
const parts = timezoneString.split(':');
const timezone = (parts[0] === '-' ? -1 : 1) * (parseInt(parts[1]) + (parseInt(parts[2]) / 60.0));
const timeZoneMillis = timezone * 3600 * 1000;
const now = new Date();
const inZone = new Date(now.getTime() + timeZoneMillis);
console.log(now, inZone);
```

Something like this would convert them to a millisecond timestamp and subtract that many hours and convert it back to a date.

Comment: With your special format of 'operator:hours:minutes' you just convert it to hours. See updated code.

Comment: Alternatively you can also convert it to minutes to avoid precision issues in the `/ 60.0` with `(parts[0] === '-' ? -1 : 1) * (parseInt(parts[1]) * 60 + parseInt(parts[2]))` and change line 4 to `timezone * 60 * 1000`.

Answer (score 0):

Add 24 to your `FT` value and take division remain of 24:

```
function CalcTime(UTCTIME, TIMEZONEOFFSETTIME) {
      if (oparator == "+") {
        var FT = UTCTIME + TIMEZONEOFFSETTIME;
      } else {
        var FT = UTCTIME - TIMEZONEOFFSETTIME + 24;
        FT = FT % 24;
      }

      FT = FT.toFixed(2);
      floatToTime(FT);
    }
```

Working sample: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VqQqoo